# Systemd, restart service when ip address changed

Tags: systemd

I wrote a pretty simple service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service on interface %I

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/lib/project/my_script.sh start %I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Which I start like `systemclt start myservice@net0`, where `net0` is a network interface. How can I restart the service every time the network interface is restarted?

Comment: There usually are if-up.d, if-down.d, or if-postdown.d, if-preup.d respectively on your system somewhere in /etc. They contain scripts that are called before an interface comes up or after it goes down. Not sure though if it triggers when you simply change the IP address...

Comment: Those are only present on Debian/Ubuntu IIRC. Definitely not with systemd-networkd (I was talking about adding them the other day, they resisted).

Comment: That means that, for now, is not possible to do what I'm trying?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have your systemd unit bind (`BindTo`) and depend on (`DependsOn`) the `.device` unit for the corresponding network interface (which is automatically loaded) for the said interface as so:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service on interface %I
BindsTo=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/lib/project/my_script.sh start %I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You'll probably want to have the unit's dependency formalized by adding `Wants` and `After` if your custom unit expects to have the network interface *actually online* by adding these in the `[Unit]` section:

```
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
```

NB: You can verify that `.device` units are `loaded` by doing `systemctl list-units --type=device`.

Comment: What if I want to restart if ip changes on any interface ?! any idea ? I don't want to BondTo every present interfaces, I would like to use something dynamic. but I can't figure out the proper Service/device to listen to.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could work: https://clinta.github.io/run-service-on-ip-change/

```
# /etc/systemd/system/ip-change-mon.service

[Unit]
Description=IP Change Monitor
Wants=network.target
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=:/bin/bash -c "ip mon addr | sed -nu -r
\'s/.*[[:digit:]]+:[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+).*/\\1/p\' | while read iface; do
systemctl restart ip-changed@${iface}.target; done"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target default.target
```